# TinyMCE disallow HTML TAGS on startup

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinyxml

I am using TinyMCE and I notice that as soon as you input data in it,

**TinyMCE warp this content it in a HTML TAG in my case p.**

I wold like change this Beauvoir and disallow TinyMCE to insert any HTML TAGS when is loaded.

User can format the "content" using TinyMCE toolbar (and just at that moment HTML Tags will be added)

Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. The reason for this is that each letter needs to be inside a html-element in order to style it and to perform other tasks.

Comment: @Gibbok, if this answers your question accept this as the answer so that others know you are satisfied and that Thariama gets credit.